# Can I use swift 1.2 with iOS 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I tried using swift 2 but when Xcode 7 converted it I got 60 errors. I can't use Xcode 6 with my iPhone running iOS 9, it says my phone isn't compatible. So is there any way to get my app written with swift 1.2 onto my iPhone running iOS 9 without converting to swift 2.0? ( BTW I have an older version of my app still left on my phone that was put on when I had iOS 8 written with swift 1 and it seems to work but I just can't put anything on through Xcode now)

Comment: if I were you I re-write all my code in swift 2.0

Comment: Fix the errors, that is part of a developers job. 60 errors is not that many.

Comment: you should be able to just press the auto convert button which will fix most of the errors. Also, swift 2.0 isnt that different from swift 1.2

Comment: I used the auto conversion. That's the amount of errors after conversion

Comment: I cannot believe that the errors are so difficult to fix that they are worth staying on Swift 1.2. Swift 2 has much more functionality that Swift 1.2 and probably has bug fixes as well. I strongly urge you to agree the conversion and fix the bugs. Worst case, post a new question with an error and what you have attempted to fix it so far.

Answer (score 3):

If you have both Xcode 6 and Xcode 7 installed, you can open Xcode 7 and let it connect to your device, then close it and open Xcode 6 and it should recognize the device.

Comment: How do I let it connect to my device? Do I have to run the app from Xcode 7?

Comment: It just does it automatically, I think. You might want to let it "process symbol files" for a while if it hasn't already done that.

Comment: Ok it now let's me select my phone but when I try to run it it gives me a pop up that says this iPhone may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of xcode

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try but a possible approach can be the following:

1. From Xcode 6 upload your app to App Store for internal testing (`Test Flight`)
2. From `iTunes Connect` > `Users and Roles` send an email invitation (for Test Flight) to your email address
3. From your iPhone running iOS 9 download `Test Flight` from the App Store
4. From your iPhone open the mail you received and follow the link.

Hope it helps.